Torch light effect
I want to implement a torch with in my pygame platformer, I don't know how to do it and so I need help on that. I have the lamp image, all I need is the light around a certain area of the lamp.

When I search for "pygame lighting", I get lots of results offering solutions, guides, or even full code plugins to add to a project. How have you tried implementing this effect so far, using this wealth of information and tools? Where specifically in the process did you get stuck and need help? What do you need from us that's not already documented in these sources?
